# Lost password link on custom login form page needs two clicks

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication

I have included a "Lost password?" link on a custom login page (/login) by copying the code directly from wp-login.php:

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( wp_lostpassword_url() ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Lost your password?' ); ?></a>
```

The first time the lost password link is clicked on my custom page, it doesn't take the user to the reset password form, it just refeshes the custom page and adds this to the URL:

> /login/?action=reset-password

This is my htaccess, in case it's relevant:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /devsite1/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /devsite1/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

If I click the link again, it works as normal. How can I make this work the first time it's clicked?

Comment: It sounds like this is intended, but it is hard to say with this little information given. Can you verify if the page actually gets reloaded and if with redirects, which redirects are in place?

Comment: Updated question with clarification on both points (hopefully)

Comment: well not really. that configuration snipet _might_ be related but is far away / disconnected to the problem description and may only invite to look for wrong things.